# EN R no consigo abrir xlsx

Tags: r

Estoy intentando abrir un xlsx con R y no lo consigo.

He hecho lo siguiente:

```
install.packages("XLConnect")
library (XLConnect)
wb <- loadWorkbook ("mi_fichero.xlsx", create= TRUE)
```

Comment: Que NO consigas abrir el archivo se puede deber a muchas cosas. Es importante (aparte de poner el código de forma simple como lo has hecho) poner el mensaje de error también. De todas formas te recomiendo usar un paquete mas _actualizado_ como lo es [`readxl`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readxl/README.html).

Answer (score 1):

A mi me funciona correctamente esto:

```
install.packages("xlsx")
library(xlsx)

x <- read.xlsx("rutadondetengastufichero.xlsx",sheetIndex=1,header=T)
```

Ruta de donde tengas el fichero debe estar expresada o con `\\` o con `/`
el sheetIndex se refiere a la hoja del excel que quieras importar
y el header a si tiene encabezado para el nombre de las columnas.

espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score -3):

> install.packages("readxl")
>   Installing package into ‘C:/Users/luis flores/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   Warning: package ‘readxl’ is in use and will not be installed
>   install.packages("xlsx")
>   Installing package into ‘C:/Users/luis flores/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   probando la URL 'https://cran.rediris.es/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/xlsx_0.6.1.zip'
>   Content type 'application/zip' length 458723 bytes (447 KB)
>   downloaded 447 KB

package ‘xlsx’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
        C:\Users\luis flores\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWCukSs\downloaded_packages

> library("xlsx")
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘xlsx’:
>    .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
>     call: fun(libname, pkgname)
>     error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry

Comment: Hola Luis, bienvenido. Esto no parece ser una respuesta al problema de la pregunta, si no una pregunta nueva. Has de pulsar en Formular una pregunta arriba a la derecha para hacer una nueva pero antes recuerda leer el [tour] y tambien [ask] para saber como funciona el sitio. Un saludo